# Term for reviewing a legal document describing procedures to see if they match those procedures implemented in a computer system?

Tags: legal-terms

I was just reviewing some legal documents which need updated to describe procedures implemented in a computer system to see if they match. Is there a legal term to describe this action?

Comment: Reconciliation? I'm not sure what you mean by "legal term" though, legal documents are supposed to be in "unambiguous English (or other language)", the "term" you are looking for just needs to describe what you are doing.

Comment: @RonBeyer The documents I'm reviewing are Internal Controls documents...are those considered legal documents?

Comment: Not really unless they legally bind one party or another...